# Limit MS SQL DB Index Size using Archival Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

In the project I'm working with, we have a table which sees a lot of read/write activity.

It's sort of a "visibilities" table; a background job is constantly running to generate records into this table based on the creation of other business domain entities.

This table needs to get searched against (and is being updated) on a regular basis, and we're running into performance problems because of it.

When we introduce indexes to improve the speed of search, it causes timeout issues with writing to the table when people perform updates. The table is relatively large and the search criteria is a bit complex so the indexes are large.

What I'm wondering, is if I added an "archived" bit column to the table, consistently marked somewhat old records as archived, could I re-structure the indexes to only index data which is Archived=0? Would that allow me to reduce the size of the indexes (and thus the performance impact of writing to those tables)?

I would assume no since the indexes must still consider which records are archived or not, but I'm not a SQL expert so I wanted to check.

If that would not be an ideal setup, what might I do to accomplish a similar result?

Comment: This might be a time to explore table partitioning and maybe indexed views.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Filtered Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017), which can index only the columns where `Archived=0`, and can be used only in queries that specify `WHERE Archived=0 and ...`.